# How to set Alt+mouse drag to move the window and Ctrl+mouse to resize the window unity (fresh install of 20.04)

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager

I fresh installed ubuntu 20.04 today and found the alt+mouse drag for move  and ctrl+mouse drag for resize doesn't work. How can I turn the function on? (I don't know why ubuntu people didn't set it as default).
ADD : I found under setting-keyboard short - windows, the default window move is Alt+F7 and window resize is Alt+F8.  I want to change it to Alt+mouse  and Ctrl+mouse which is quicker. How can I change it? (I tried but didn't work)

Comment: do you know if it's an option included in the gnome-tweaks app? https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-tweak-tool-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: @jad hi, I've been using it in Xfce4 and unity window manager. Do you mean I can use it in unity by installing gnome-tweaks app?

Comment: Clarify which desktop environment you use. You refer to Unity, but then you refer to a default Ubuntu 20.04 install. Then you are probably not using Unity, but Gnome Shell.

Comment: @vanadium isn't the purple window gui the Unity? I fresh installed 20.04 and it began with that purple GUI. and I don't know what 'Focal Fossa linux' is in the link jed showed me. The GUI looks almost the same with on in the link though.

Comment: `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in terminal will show what desktop environment you use

Comment: Ah, it says "ubuntu:GNOME" and just learnd 20.04 name is Focal Fossa. :)

Answer (score 18):

Someone thought that changing the key to <kbd>Super</kbd> (aka<kbd>Windows</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>) was a good idea to resolve some other conflicts for the design crowd. Frustrating. To restore the Gnome 2 defaults of <kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier '<Alt>'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true
```

If you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then you can substitute `<Ctrl>` above, but I think you might be mistaken, chances of conflicting key combinations  involving that are even higher.

The default to resize from anywhere was changed to <kbd>Super + middle click drag</kbd>. Of course the above restores that too.

Comment: Sometimes the solution pops up only a few months later. Thanks! Spot on! It is not possible to have Alt for move then Ctrl for resize - for both, the same windows action key is in effect.

Comment: Hi now I usually work with 'terminator' window. It's very convenient so I don't need to move or resize windows as ofter as before. But thans for the answer.

Comment: For those unaware (such as myself), the "Super key" is the Windows or ⌘ key. See [What is the Super key?](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-key-super.html.en)

Comment: can also be set in `dconf-editor` for a GUI experience

Answer (score 0):

In KDE, in System Settings, it's under Window Management, Window Behavior, Window Actions, Inner Window, Modifier key. It's selected to Meta, and change that to Alt.